# qpaeq No module named 'dbus.mainloop.pyqt5'

Tags: pulseaudio, qt5

I'm trying to set up `qpaeq` under Ubuntu. It returns me this error

```
There was an error importing needed libraries
Make sure you have qt5 and dbus-python installed
The error that occurred was:
    No module named 'dbus.mainloop.pyqt5'
```

The module is installed though

```
python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 is already the newest version (5.14.1+dfsg-3build1).
```

But it's not found by python, and I can't figure out why

```
(base) arthur@arthur-laptopt:~$ python 
Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 19:58:26) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dbus.mainloop.pyqt5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbus.mainloop.pyqt5'
```

My Ubuntu version is

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

What do I need to do so `qpaeq` sees `dbus.mainloop.pyqt5` ?